# Create class declaration programmatically in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Eventually what I need is to build a class declaration at runtime providing dynamic parameters to a property annotation:

```
import {Type} from "external-module";

export default class TypeWrapper {

    @Type(() => '{this part of the class declaration should be changable at runtime}')
    data

}
```

I have a feeling that this should be possible to achieve but can't figure out a proper way yet.

As a proof of concept I was trying to do something like below:

```
let MyClass = eval('(class MyClass{})')
let myClass = new MyClass()
```

That works, however `MyClass` needs to define some imports:

```
        let MyClass = eval('import {Type} from "external-module"' +
            '(class MyClass{})')
```

That one fails with "`Cannot use import statement outside a module`" which is quite expected.

Another approach I tried is to load a module from string:

```
        var moduleData = '' +
            'import module from "./module/path/file.js"\n' +
            '\n' +
            'export default class MyClass {\n' +
            '}\n' +
            '\n';
        var b64moduleData = "data:text/javascript;base64," + btoa(moduleData);


        let MyClass = await import(b64moduleData)
```

But it fails with "`Cannot find module`", suggesting it assumes `b64moduleData` is a path rather than module data itself.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: _"let MyClass = eval('class MyClass{}') let myClass = new MyClass"_: that works?

Comment: @Andy, yes, that part does work, fixed typos though.

Comment: better not use eval but return a class from a function like shown below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, for this type of thing I would use a class factory:

```
import { Type } from 'some-module';

function createClass(parameters) {
  return class {
    ....
  }
}

const MyClass = createClass(...);
```

I'm unsure if this fits your particular use case based on the details provided.

EDIT: As a side-note, as far as I know, you cannot construct modules from a string, which is what your code is doing, and what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed! Didn't know that syntax, thanks man!